# What is the template of Wiktionary in .bz2 dump file?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

I downloaded the file `frwiktionary-20210401-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2` from [here](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/frwiktionary/20210401/). It's mentioned that this file contains

> Articles, templates, media/file descriptions, and primary meta-pages, in multiple bz2 streams, 100 pages per stream.

1. What is the *template* mentioned here? Is it the template to convert wikitext to html?
2. I tried opening the file with UltraEdit and got, for example,

[image]

and

[image]

I could not see any template in this file.

Could you please elaborate on these 2 issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Template" in this sense refers to [MediaWiki templates](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates). Pages in the Template [namespace](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Namespaces) can be transcluded into other pages using double curly brackets, like `{{foobar}}`.

In the last screenshot in the question, [`es-phrase`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Template:es-phrase), [`lb`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Template:lb), [`cot`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Template:cot) and [`uxi`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Template:uxi) are templates.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67403599/how-to-add-template-from-xml-dump-to-my-mediawiki)? Thank you so much for your dedicated help :))